# conn.beginTransaction is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Does someone know, why i get this error: `TypeError: conn.beginTransaction is not a function`? I've been trying to find how to use transaction with mysql2, but haven't found a good solution yet.

**dbConfig.js**

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    connectionLimit: 10,
});

module.exports = pool;
```

**ProductModel.js**

```js
const conn = require('../config/dbConfig');

const productModel = {
    postOrder: async (order) => {
        return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            conn.beginTransaction();
            console.log('Start Tranaction!');
            const insertQuery = conn.query(
                'INSERT INTO `beansome`.`order` (`orderCreated`,`orderFirstname`,`orderLastname`,`orderStreet`,`orderHousenumber`,`orderZipcode`,`orderCity`,`orderTelephone`,`orderEmail`,`orderTotalprice`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);',
                [
                    order.orderCreated,
                    order.orderFirstname,
                    order.orderLastname,
                    order.orderStreet,
                    order.orderHousenumber,
                    order.orderZipcode,
                    order.orderCity,
                    order.orderTelephone,
                    order.orderEmail,
                    order.orderTotalprice,
                ]
            );

            conn.commit();
            console.log('End Tranaction!');
        });
    },
};
module.exports = productModel;
```

Comment: Have you declared beginTransaction function somewhere? If you have not declared or it is not a built-in function, an error is returned.

Comment: No, I haven't declared it. 
Where do i need to do that?

Comment: It seems beginTransaction() is SQL Server function. I am not familiar with the SQL Server version.

Comment: You importing `ConnectionPool` from **dbConfig.js**, not `Connection`. `beginTransaction` is the connection method. [Also it might be useful](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/384).